# Heroku with Docker release failed - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users.apps'

Tags: python, django, git, docker, heroku

I've been following a book tutorial that uses docker with Django. When I used the command 'git push heroku master', I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users.apps'
```

Throughout this project, I have also been having issues installing with pipenv inside my container, which required a workaround. I'm thinking that issue could be related. Regardless, here is my heroku.yml file:

```
setup:
  addons:
  - plan: heroku-postgresql
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
run:
  web: gunicorn bookstore_project.wsgi
```

And my docker-compose.prod.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn bookstore_project.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000

    environment: 
      - ENVIRONMENT=production
      - SECRET_KEY=[removed]
      - DEBUG=0
      - STRIPE_TEST_PUBLISHABLE_KEY= [removed]
      - STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY= [removed]
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
```

Lastly, the installed apps section of my Django settings.py that contains the users app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    

    # Third-party
    'crispy_forms',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    #gmail specific - see config at https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#google
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'debug_toolbar',

    # Local
    # Added for custom user model
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'books.apps.BooksConfig',
    'orders.apps.OrdersConfig',

]
```

I tried installing an updated python image in the container, but I'm not sure how to reconfigure the entire project to run on my new python version (or if that's even possible at this point), so I hit a dead end.